# US66309967A and US3462767 flush valve

Tags: owner

US66309967A  and US3462767 flush valve patents.  My father Harold F Larson & Robert L Schultz designed a few patents.  They sold the rights I would like to know who?

Comment: I looked in the recordation database https://assignment.uspto.gov/patent/index.html#/patent/search it says it has nothing earlier than August 1980.  There are undoubtedly microfilm records for earlier patents.

Answer (score 1):

I found [four patents](https://patents.google.com/?inventor=Harold%20F%20Larson&dups=language) with Harold F Larson listed as an inventor. Two are for flush valves: [US3341863A](https://patents.google.com/patent/US3341863A/en?oq=US3341863A) and [US3462767A](https://patents.google.com/patent/US3462767A/en?oq=US3462767A). US66309967A has too many digits to be a patent and doesn't show up in a search. Looking at the text of US3462767A I see: "N. Dak. 58421 Filed Aug. 24, 1967, Ser. No. 663,099" so I believe that is maybe an application number and US66309967A is just a typo in Google Patents.

I tried looking in the [US Public Pair](https://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair) and the [USPTO Global Dossier](https://globaldossier.uspto.gov/#/) and found nothing at all. Based on comments by George White, my guess is the patents are just too old. You may be able to get the patents file wrappers from the the USPTO for a fee. My understanding is that licensing deals done post grant are not often registered with the USPTO so I don't think there is any way to figure out who the patents were licensed to beyond what you might be able to find through a Google search. Understand that the patents expired many years ago.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite Good to know. Thanks...

Comment: I just checked and found that some applications filed in 1982 are in PAIR so they have added more old data than they had previously.

Comment: You can get old file wrappers on paper or PDF from the USPTO for a per page fee.